# Java - coupling String and storing in array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to take a user's input as a String `hex` and split it into couples; then I want to store each couple in an array `hexArray`. In other words, I want to split the String at every two chars. I was thinking about maybe inserting a `-` at every two chars and using `String.split()` to split it, but this is the method that I have devised. Take the user's input for `hex` to be `"1234567"` in this case. This is what I have so far:

```
    //removes last character from hex if length is odd and stores it back in hex
    hex = hex.length() % 2 == 0 ? hex : hex.substring(0, hex.length() - 1);

    String [] hexArray = new String[hex.length()/2];

    //initializes and prints the first element of the array as the first two chars
    //of hex
    System.out.println(hexArray[0] = hex.substring(0, 2));
    for (int i = 1; i + 3 < hex.length(); i++)
    {     
        System.out.println(hexArray[i] = hex.substring(i + 1, i + 3));

    }
```

The output of this is

```
12
34
45
```

I have altered the termination statement in the for loop in every way I can think of. If this were to compile correctly, it would output

```
12
34
56
```

I initiated the first element of the array simply to avoid the case of `i = 0`. How can I avoid this overlap? Also, is there any way to convert each element of `hexArray` from hex to decimal form (assuming the chars of `hex` consist of input 0-9 and A-F (case insensitive)), and then concatenate the elements of `hexArray` into one String? TIA.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what your input will be vs expected output ?

Comment: If I were to input `1234567`, the expected output would be 
    12
    34
    56
all stored in an array

Comment: and what is the reasoning behind this? because that input to hex is 12D687, or is it just spacing every two chars ?

Comment: It's for a program I'm working on, but I'm just stuck at the point of splitting `hex` at every 2 characters and storing each split section into an array `hexArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your for loop next way:

```
    for (int i = 0; i * 2 + 2 <= hex.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(hexArray[i] = hex.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2));

    }
```

No need for special treatment of `i = 0`.

Logic behind it is that your array position should be half of current string position. Also you can do this kind of comparison `i * 2 + 2 <= hex.length()` cause substrings upper bound is not inclusive.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't seem to figure out the arithmetic involved in `i` - I tried so many combinations

Answer (score 1):

Obviously assuming that the string length could either be even or odd, you will have to primarily handle that case first. Appending 0's at the beginning of your hex won't do any harm, padding issues, solve it like this

```
    String str = "123";
    String hex = "";
    while( ( str.length() % 2 ) != 0 )
    {
        str = "0" + str;
    }
```

Once you handle this you can compile the whole things as

```
    String str = "123";
    String hex = "";
    while( ( str.length() % 2 ) != 0 )
    {
        str = "0" + str;
    }
    System.out.println( str );
    for( int x = 0; x < str.length(); x++ )
    {
        hex += str.charAt(x);
        if( ( (x + 1) % 2) == 0 )
        {
            hex += '-';
        }
    }
    if( hex.endsWith("-") )
    {
        hex = hex.substring( 0 , hex.length() - 1);
    }
    System.out.println( hex );
    String[] hexArray = hex.split("-");
    System.out.println( java.util.Arrays.toString(hexArray) );
```

So, inside the loop, at ever eventh iteration, we append an '-' to the string. But since that could leave an unwanted "-" at the end of the string, we just make sure to remove that case by using **hex = hex.substring( 0 , hex.length() - 1);** This will give you the string that you desire. **if( ( (x + 1) % 2) == 0 )** just really makes sure that we are not testing **is (0 % 2) == 0?**

Finally for generating an array that holds every pair, you can do this

```
    String[] hexArray = hex.split("-");
    System.out.println( java.util.Arrays.toString(hexArray) );
```

Hope that helps your case??

Answer (score 1):

you can use *regular expression* to split every two characters

```
String str = "1234567";
// if the string length is not even we remove the last char.
str = (str.length()%2==0)?str: str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
// this regex matches every two chars, so it will split every two chars
String[] split = str.split("(?<=\\G..)");
for(String s: split){
 System.out.println(s); // prints 12 34 56
}
```

Comment: You really nailed it with **regular expression** phenomena :) , but what about ******7 case?? Oh yes I just forgot, he wants it to be removed :D . Really nice answer though